# Is it possible to do google API sign in from the server side and pass the result to user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-hangouts

I have an app that clients can pick a time to book a video appointment and I just want to send them the Google Hangouts Meet link. For this purpose I'm using google calendar API in my JavaScript code from this document https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events it works and I can create the link fine. But my question is that is there any way that I can create the link based on the time that they select on server side (node js) with a Gsuite account and just send them the link at the end? (I don't want to create event on their Google calendar or send them notification from Google) I don't want the user to prompt with Google login page for authorization. I just need to create the link and send it to the client.Is this possible?
I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: You could: 1) Create an event with your account and send them the meet link. 2) If you're a G Suite admin you can use a service account with [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) to impersonate each user and create the event in their behalf without them having to sign-in and then send them the meet link. Would one of those help you? otherwise please provide more explanation of what you need and the code you're using to create the event and get the meet link.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I read through "domain-wide delegation", and I did the settings and got the json file for settings at the end. But I cannot find any example for nodejs to see how can I use this and how to implement this in my own code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code from this [guide](http://isd-soft.com/tech_blog/accessing-google-apis-using-service-account-node-js/) to auhtenticate with a service account and searching in this [examples](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/e11e18cb33eb60a666980d061c54bb8891cdd242/test/test.jwt.ts) from the google-auth nodejs repository to see how to set the `subject` parameter which is the used to impersonate a user, I was able to get the authenticated JWT auth client object which can be used to make google API requests like [listing the events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs) of the impersonated user:

```
let google = require('googleapis').google;
let privatekey = require("./[JSON-FILENAME].json");

// configure a JWT auth client
let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    privatekey.client_email,
    null,
    privatekey.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
    '[EMAIL-OF-USER-TO-IMPERSONATE]'
);
//authenticate request
jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully connected!");
    }
});

listEvents(jwtClient);

function listEvents(auth) {
    const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });
    calendar.events.list({
        calendarId: 'primary',
        timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
        maxResults: 10,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime',
    }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        const events = res.data.items;
        if (events.length) {
            console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
            events.map((event, i) => {
                const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
                console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);
            });
        } else {
            console.log('No upcoming events found.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Andres! I ended up using this code: https://hackernoon.com/my-journey-integrating-google-calendar-g-suite-in-node-62fbc8596455

Comment: But I don't understand why you used JWT?

Comment: With JWT it's the only way I found in the whole repository to set the impersonated user. You can post your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) as well and accept it.